# x509 certificate verification issue

Tags: x.509, ecc

Having issue with x509 certificate verification.

Steps I followed.

1. Generated the root certificate.
2. created the  Intermediate certificate.
3. signed the Intermediate certificate with root certificate.
4. Signing was success.
5. verification failed.
6. which fields should be same to make verification successful?

Comment: Please provide details. It is not clear how have you created root certificate, what fields were used in CSR for the root certificate. The same is not clear about intermediate certificate. It is not clear what tools have you used. It is not clear how have you verified.

Comment: When asking for troubleshooting help, please provide the actual commands/process used and the actual output, not just your summary. All you've said is "I did something and it didn't work"